# Laravel: access the <body> of index.html from dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a snippet to the body tag of index.html (or index.php) and I have no access to the file system, just access to Laravel dashboard:
[image]

Is it possible to somehow edit the index.php through the dashboard?
It seems that I can only get access to the pages (such as the homepage and other pages)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you be more specific? The dashboard of what?

Comment: The backend dashboard like a CMS. I'm sorry for being unclear I will add a screenshot right now, thanks

Comment: @sir-haver You can add your widget in layout file, that's where you will see `<body>` definition. If i got your question right. the layout file located at `resources->views->layouts`

Comment: Hello Seghei, by resources did you mean sources? I do not have a resources tab. Or did you mean a folder named 'resources'? I don't have access to the files. Thanks

Comment: @sir-haver i mean folder

Comment: I cannot access the folders as the client doesn't know who's their hosting provider

Comment: that's bad, because the `$content` of view file is rendered \\ displayed from the layout file. In over words, you can not modify layout of your views. You have to have access to root of your app to do that

Comment: Check by ip, or domain.name who is the hosting provider, Or check domain name  NS records, where they looks.

Comment: I see, yes I already tried by the ip and domain name but it cannot be found. Thanks anyway Serghei

Comment: By **just access to Laravel dashboard**, you mean you have no **FTP** access?

Comment: Yes, I don't have

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have FTP access, the short answer to your question is **you can't** (as a developer). but you may be able as a user, if the **backend** exposes a view for this kind of changes.

### OR

If you just want to make this change in browser (Temporary, lost on page reload), you can use the developer tools, making some DOM manipulation using the **Elements** tab.

Comment: Thanks Omer yes I'm trying to add a snippet, not to make a temporary change of course.
I understand that it's just impossible without access to the ftp